# Update graph in real time from server

Tags: javascript, jquery, graph, d3.js, data-visualization

I'm trying to update a graph with received data, so that the height of the bars increase as more data is received from the server via a websocket. But my code doesn't render a graph in the browser and plot the data points. I cannot see anything wrong with the code. I really need some help here please.

```
  ws = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8888/dh");

  var useData = []
  //var chart;

  var chart = d3.select("body")
     .append("svg:svg")
     .attr("class", "chart")
     .attr("width", 420)
     .attr("height", 200);


  ws.onmessage = function(evt)
  {  
    var distances = JSON.parse(evt.data);
    data  = distances.miles;
    console.log(data);

    if(useData.length <= 10){
      useData.push(data)
    }
    else
    {

       var draw = function(data){        
       // Set the width relative to max data value
       var x = d3.scale.linear()
        .domain([0, d3.max(useData)])
        .range([0, 420]);

       var y = d3.scale.ordinal()
        .domain(useData)
        .rangeBands([0, 120]);

       var rect = chart.selectAll("rect")
        .data(useData)

        // enter rect
        rect.enter().append("svg:rect")
            .attr("y", y)
            .attr("width", x)
            .attr("height", y.rangeBand());

        // update rect            
        rect
            .attr("y", y)
            .attr("width", x)
            .attr("height", y.rangeBand());

       var text = chart.selectAll("text")
            .data(useData)

       // enter text
       text.enter().append("svg:text")
            .attr("x", x)
            .attr("y", function (d) { return y(d) + y.rangeBand() / 2; })
            .attr("dx", -3) // padding-right
            .attr("dy", ".35em") // vertical-align: middle
            .attr("text-anchor", "end") // text-align: right
            .text(String);

        // update text
        text
            .data(useData)
            .attr("x", x)
            .text(String);
    }
draw();
useData.length = 0;
   }          
}
```

Thanks

EDIT:

However the problem now is that it doesn't seem to add the new data to the existing bars, rather the old values are replaced instead. How could I get the new values to be added to the existing bar values. So for example if bar 'A' has a value of 7, when the new data comes for bar 'A' of value 9 then the bar should now be 16 NOT 9. jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2NXF2/31/

Comment: I'm almost tempted to vote for close as "too localized", as there is just too many custom functions and other stuff going on there, but does the message arrive, and can you see it in the console.log, if so the problem is with the output to the browser, if there's nothing being logged or an error occured, you should see it in the console ?

Comment: Also, it does'nt look like you are calling the `draw()` function anywhere, which would explain the lack of drawing ?

Comment: Yes message does arrive and I can view it on the console log

Comment: Are you calling that draw() function somewhere else then, or not at all ?

Comment: I'm not calling it anywhere...I've new to d3 and visualisation so I'm not 100% here.

Comment: It's a function, unless you call it, it will never run ???

Comment: I been stuck at this for hours and feel really stupid now. So could I call it before useData.length = 0; as draw()?

Comment: I would just place that function outside the if/else logic, and call it in the else part if that is where it's suppose to be called, and I'm assuming it needs some data as a parameter, like this [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/m52Mh/) ??

Comment: Thanks I was able to draw the graph ok as in the EDIT to the original question...only problem is as I've also included in the edit.

Comment: I really have no idea? You're using an array and d3 to populate the graph, and I'm not really familiar with that solution at all. You should try asking it as a new question, and try to include the technologies you're using in the title, so as to grab the attention of anyone who has experience with this sort of thing. Usually weekdays are better for asking questions, as it seems there are more people on then.

Comment: OK I'll revise the title and question to. My impression of d3 was that it required an array. But thanks for your help and tips.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There appears to be no expression to aggregate new data with the old data from the previous iteration. `useData.length = 0` wipes out the existing data completely and `useData.push(data)` pushes only a single element onto the the empty `useData` array. I'm guessing that this does not yield data in the necessary format to be plotted.

Also, I may be missing something here but there appears to be no reason for the `draw()` function to be inside the `ws.onmessage` handler. By defining `draw()` outside the handler, it is defined once rather than being redefined every time `ws.onmessage` fires.

If I'm right then the code just needs a bit of rearrangement, plus a little loop in a much reduced `ws.onmessage` handler to aggregate the new miles with the old :

```
var ws = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8888/dh");
var useData = [12,45,48,45,654,12,465,5,12,45];
var chart = d3.select("body").append("svg:svg").attr("class", "chart").attr("width", 420).attr("height", 200);

function draw() {
    // Set the width relative to max data value
    var x = d3.scale.linear().domain([0, d3.max(useData)]).range([0, 420]);
    var y = d3.scale.ordinal().domain(useData).rangeBands([0, 120]);
    var rect = chart.selectAll("rect").data(useData);
    // enter rect
    rect.enter().append("svg:rect").attr("y", y).attr("width", x).attr("height", y.rangeBand());
    // update rect            
    rect.attr("y", y).attr("width", x).attr("height", y.rangeBand());
    var text = chart.selectAll("text").data(useData);
    // enter text
    text.enter().append("svg:text").attr("x", x).attr("y", function(d) {
        return y(d) + y.rangeBand() / 2;
    }).attr("dx", -3) // padding-right
      .attr("dy", ".35em") // vertical-align: middle
      .attr("text-anchor", "end") // text-align: right
      .text(String);
    // update text
    text.data(useData).attr("x", x).text(String);
};

draw();//initialise with hard-coded useData

//Now, aggregate additional miles when ws.onmessage fires and redraw the graph.
ws.onmessage = function(evt) {
    var distances = JSON.parse(evt.data);
    for(var i=0; i<useData.length; i++) {
        if(useData[i] && distances.miles[i]) {//safety
            useData[i] += distances.miles[i];//add the new miles to the total from previous iteration
        }
    }
    draw();//redraw the graph
}
```

Notes: 
 - I'm not familiar with d3, so I've not tried to verify the `draw()` function.
 - I've made a number of guesses, so there's probably still some work to do.